# inputSelect after render error [Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null]

Tags: visualforce, lightning, managed-package, ui

I have this inputSelect

```
<ui:inputSelect value="{!v.cardType}" disabled="{!v.memberCard.isFirstHousehold}" class="slds-select" aura:id="assignToSelect" change="{!c.updateSelectedCardType}">
  <ui:inputSelectOption text="contact" label="{!v.labels.at_memberCard_contactOption}"/>
  <ui:inputSelectOption text="guest" label="{!v.labels.at_memberCard_nameOnCardOption}"/>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

It works, gets displayed properly and all..  but I keep getting this error message at the bottom of the screen:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. afterRender threw an error in 'markup://ui:inputSelect' [Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null] Failing descriptor: {markup://ui:inputSelect}

Anybody else had similar problems?

Comment: Whatever getelementbytagename is attached to is null. Maybe in the change handler?

Comment: I thought about that, but even removing that change call, it still give me the null, and the variables assigned on the value and label I also set them static value and still gives the same error message at the bottom.